# Disable controller in tvOS

Tags: swift, tvos, apple-tv

I would like to have a feature in an `Apple TV` app where if one controller is typing in a `UITextField`, the other is temporarily disabled so only the controller that opened it can control the actions. I looked at the API guide for `GCController` and I was unable to find anything so I was just wondering if this was possible.